# Strategy for fast IOS contacts "friend finder"

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, ruby-on-rails-4

Example:

- Snapchat - Add Friends(from phone contacts)
- Twitter - Find Friends(from phone contacts)

I have no problems extracting names, phone numbers, email addresses from the IOS device contacts. I have been experimenting with different approaches and strategies to:

- Upload contacts to web server
- Compare list with server database using phone numbers and email addresses (not necessary to store a copy)
- Return a list of contacts who are also users and who are not

My attempts takes roughly 30-45 seconds for 500 contacts. The same set of contacts takes 2-5 seconds roughly for snapchat or twitter to work with.

What is their secret? Good obj-c coding? Good database design? I appreciate that they would have highly efficient hosting stacks but I wasn't expecting that kind of time difference.

Is it better to:

1. Try a bulk upload of all contacts and return a json string with hits and misses.
2. A single HTTP request for each?
3. Opening some kind of persistent connection like a websocket to check each contact?
4. Some other obvious strategy or approach I haven't considered yet?

Comment: Hello, you would demonstrate the solution to the contacts list? My solution takes a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the key is to make the request smaller by utilizing a single piece of contact information for the search rather than using names, numbers, and email addresses. If your service requires any of those pieces for sign up, like the phone number, use just the phone number. When you return info from your server, don't send anything you don't need, like the phone numbers you couldn't find a match for.

Secondly, your option #3 isn't a bad idea if you have the technical know-how. I recommend a library called [SocketRocket](http://corner.squareup.com/2012/02/socketrocket-websockets.html). It was developed by the people who make Square and makes implementing websockets on your front-end very easy.

I can't speak to your back end, but I use node.js and this package: https://github.com/einaros/ws Very easy to install (`npm install ws`) and also easy to use.

Comment: I ruled out the Web Socket route. There seems to be big issues when the device was behind a proxy. Without further info, I would guess IOS 7 doesn't share/include proxy info with 3rd party apps. 

I went for really minimising the data I send. The code isn't as verbose any more but I have my response times down to 2 seconds for 1500 contacts. That's comparing phone numbers and email addresses. Those times will probably slow down once the database is populated with a few million records. 

I'll need to look at indexing and additional read servers then but that will be a good problem to have.

Comment: If anyone requires it, I can post a more detailed description of my approach client side in Objective-C and on server side with MySQL and Rails 4.

Comment: Hey Chabber, I know you posted this a little while ago, but if you still remember the approach you took, I would be very grateful if you can post it. I'm in a similar situation as you once were and not sure how to proceed.